# SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server

Tags: python

I am trying to send mail using python smtplib module, but I got error.

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.login("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "yyyyyyy")
message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
s.sendmail("xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "aaaaaaaaa@gmail.com", message)
s.quit()
```

I got error like below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/engineer/demo.py",
>   line 52, in 
>       s.starttls()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 637, in starttls
>       raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.") SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No changes as far as code is concerned, end up finding out, Issue was associated with enough firewall permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I refer the solution from another link. You may try to remove `s.ehlo()` before  `s.starttls()`.

I tested your code with my own gmail account, it seems the code should work with s.echlo(). You may like to check your gmail security setting eg enable **Less secure apps**, [Let less secure apps use your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

You also enable debug by using `s.set_debuglevel(1)`

`import smtplib`

`s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)`

`s.set_debuglevel(1)`

`s.ehlo()`

`s.starttls()`

Comment: Log 1/2:
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [115.118.5.146]\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 35882577\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: smtp.gmail.com at your service, [115.118.5.146]
SIZE 35882577
8BITMIME
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
PIPELINING
SMTPUTF8

Comment: Log 2/2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/engineer/mail.py", line 8, in <module>
    s.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 637, in starttls
    raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

Comment: what is the status of your **Allow less secure apps.** in your gmail setting?

Comment: Allow less secure apps :ON state

Comment: Was't require, issue was with the Firewall permissions at Office network